# Newlines are not correctly put into intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send plaintext copied from email/web to my application vi ACTION_SEND intent for futher processing. What bothers me is the fact that new lines are not correctly sent with the text.
 
For example when I have a list of items with each item on a new line, mark them and send them to my app via share option then EXTRA_TEXT of the sent intent will have all items in one line separated by one whitespace.
**Source:**
item1
item2
**EXTRA_TEXT:**
item1 item2

How ever if I copy list of items which are separated by two lines (double br between items in emails source) then EXTRA_TEXT contains items seperated by newlines.
How can I get exactly what I see in the email application or browser? Is there any other way to pass the text to intent and keep all the formating?
 I tried to change mimeType of my intent filter to text/html but then my application is not even listed as option where to send selected data.
Piece of code (just testing):

```
    if (intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Log.d("Intent_Extra:", bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)));
        try {
            String str;
            while((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("Item:", str);
            }
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Run a regex replace looking for SINGLE newlines and replace them with double newlines, as to emulate the best-case scenario where you do receive the lines separated. I know this is kludgy and the real answer would dig up to the real reason that behavior is happening but these are my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks but it probably does not solve the problem. It seems that all I am able to do is to work with the string received by intent and this string already has NO newlines. Items are separated by single whitespace and thus I cannot run any regex because I cannot be sure if this whitespace was intended or not. For example list: "Chicken<br>curry" looks exactly same as "Chicken curry" in the intent and I am not able to say if this list has oneor two items (one chicken curry food or generic chicken and some curry spice).

Comment: I somehow interpreted the question text as if you had control over the sender intent, sorry.

Comment: Well, I would like to have...unfortunately sender is other application I do not own (email client, browser, etc.).